# Why do witches don black "traffic cone" on their heads?

Tags: magic, clothing, secret-society

Witches practice a form of sorcery unlike magic, in fact they work with curses all the time. A curse is more difficult to lift, usually a witch must undergo years of training in dark culinary arts before earning the rights to wear the black pointed hat or they are affectionately called traffic cone.

With the witch hunts spreading across many states like wildfire, the last thing anyone would do is to put on a traffic cone over their heads which could easily invites trouble. My question despite the ongoing search why do witches want to don traffic cones? It's not like the hat is the source of their power nor are they courting their death.

Comment: There are 42 Terry Pratchett books you need to read ;)

Comment: @user676  In real life many thousands of persons were accused of being witches in the sense of evil devil worshippers with magic powers, and many were convicted and executed.  In real life there were no witches in the sense of evil devil worshippers with magic powers.  If there were real witches witch hunters would have been in danger of death, not witches.  It is illogical to write a story where real witches, instead of innocent bystanders,  are in any danger from any witch hunters who might be operating, & also rather insulting to the memories of victims of witch hunts.

Comment: Is the first paragraph important? I'm not sure why it matters to us how curses work. Is the point to establish that a black pointed hat is an important symbol for your witches?

Comment: *dark **culinary** arts?*  - So their skills are based on food and cooking?  That seems random, but considering @Tetsujin's point about Discworld, maybe not so far from my favourite witches.

Comment: They're chef's hats/baker's hats?

Comment: Why wear the hat? Because it's expected of them, people respect the hat, or if they don't respect it they fear it, it's much like a policeman's uniform, just wearing it bestows power & authority over others, Granny Weatherwax called this effect headology, you or I would call it psychology, besides, if they didn't advertise how would you know who to go to for that love potion or to get your neighbour cursed?

Comment: To keep the drop bears off.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Nanny Ogg even wrote her own cookbook - [Google reader link](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Nanny_Ogg_s_Cookbook/wsq-HWopsZ8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: @Tetsujin: Oh right, of course it's been published on roundworld, too, not just in Ankh Morpork :P  I think Nanny Ogg would be highly offended by any suggestion there was anything dark about her culinary arts, though.  (Although reasonable people might disagree about that wrt. her Wow-Wow sauce.)

Answer (score 8):

### No magic involved

Its purpose is not to add or enhance magic. Witches probably did not invent these hats

**Symbol of wickedness**

The black pointed hat was a medieval stigma rather than fashion. It became fashion amongst modern age "would-be" witches who have the luxury not being persecuted for their practices.

In medieval Europe, the pointed hat signified Jews. The 1215 Fourth Council of the Lateran required all Jews to identify themselves by wearing the **Judenhut**, so it is a precursor of the yellow badge.

In the 18-19th century, the hat was revived and associated with witches in stories, to show their wickedness. The earliest example I can find of this shift is in Wiki,

[image: Woodcut showing a witch on a broomstick with a conical hat, from The History of Witches and Wizards (1720)]

In Wiki there's another example of the pointed hat as a sign of *wicked women*

> Yet another hypothesis proposes that witch hats originated as **alewife hats**, distinctive headgear worn by women who home-brewed beer for
> sale. According to this suggestion, these hats gained negative
> connotations when the brewing industry, dominated by men, accused
> alewives of selling diluted or tainted beer. In combination with
> the general suspicion that women with knowledge of herbology were working in an occult domain
> , the alewife hat could have become associated with
> witchcraft

However, when searching for the origin of pointed witch hats, modern sources disagree with the idea of renaissance alewife hats being the prototype.. the church returns more often in explanations.

Many other sources can be found on the subject..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_hat

https://slate.com/human-interest/2013/10/the-history-of-the-witch-s-hat-origins-of-its-pointy-design.html

https://www.instyle.com/fashion/clothing/witch-outfit-history-theories

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_badge

https://braciatrix.com/2017/10/27/nope-medieval-alewives-arent-the-archetype-for-the-modern-pop-culture-witch/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_hat

[5] Peter Burke, Eyewitnessing: The Use of Images as Historical Evidence, (Cornell, 2000), p. 136.

Comment: Add https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_hat which points out that several "other" religions used cone hats. It could be an indication that some of these other religions still operated "underground" as it were in medieval Europe which is a definite possibility considering how Jewish customs survived underground for hundreds of years in Catholic New Mexico.

Comment: @DavidR yes, the "demonization" of these hats could very well have an earlier cause, e.g. some  competing religion. The answer I put is based on sources I could find. What's clear somewhere in the 18th-19th century stories appeared with witches wearing pointed, black hats. The judenhut and resembling alewife hat origins were the most recent sources at the time.

Answer (score 8):

These hats are based on the pentagram, and used both to attune the magical affinity and to deflect evil influences.

[image: Notice the resemblance?]

As the three points of the silhouette of the witch's hat correspond with the three upper points of the pentagram, the lower two correspond with the witch's hands.
Combined, these five points symbolize the microcosm, the five Platonic elements, the five wounds of Jesus, or [whatever else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram) suits the source of your witch's powers.

Answer (score 2):

The same reason why soldiers wear uniforms when going to war, instead of disguising as unoffensive civilians or doctors or members of the clergy: because there are conventions in place that regulate how to identify, engage and treat members of all sides involved in a war when wearing uniforms.

Just out curiosity, [expanding bullets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanding_bullet#International_law) are deemed inhuman when used in war, but are legitimately used by some police forces. I wonder what does the convention for witchcraft says...

Answer (score 2):

**Head Tentacles**

[image]

*Tentacle head lady by [Chris Pollitt](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/Klrvo)*

From communing with otherworldly forces, advanced witches have tentacles on their heads. The hat is there to hide the tentacles when they are *out*.

Of course there are less conspicuous hats they could choose to wear. But at this point in history the traffic cone hat already existed and meant other things than I am a witch.

The fact that all witches wear the same hat -- whatever it looks like -- lets witches recognize each other on the street. Or at least recognize someone who *might* be a witch. As I said non-witches wear these hats too, so you have to check is the hat moving in the wind as though it was empty or full. This is almost indiscernible unless yo know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Failure to wear a black hat when attending any gathering of witches is a mark of cowardice. It shows that you are afraid that your magic is too weak to protect you, that you can not either prevent yourself from being seen coming or going, or else prevent any witnesses from reporting you to the authorities.

No one wants to work with a cowardly witch.  You could not rely on her in moments of crisis, which are, alas, all too common in the field.

Answer (score 1):

## Tin Foil hat Lady:

*I seriously know a woman who wears tin foil under a hat to shield their brains from evil government influence. We refer to her as "tin foil hat lady." The scary thing is she's a brilliant surgeon.*

Given the sheer effectiveness of curses as difficult to reverse harming spells, the logic is that the witches hat serves a similar protective function. The hat creates a [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)) in which sorcery directed against a witches mind is trapped. It either shields or slows the effect of curses and other mind control on the brain (a bit like magneto's helmet), so a witch with a curse cast on them is able to still function to remove or reverse the curse.

The technology was first developed by the Egyptian worshippers of [Osiris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osiris), who focused on developing life-and-death magic, but was later adopted and perfected by the earliest true witches among the [Scythian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocorybantians) peoples.

[image: Osiris]

While witches *CAN* go without their hats, they are vulnerable without them on. The biggest threat to a witch isn't someone recognizing them as a witch, but the influences of other witches and the various supernatural entities (like demons) that the witches regularly deal with. Most people persecuted for being witches aren't free-willed witches but ones that are either students (and thus expendable) or rival witches (in which case the witch hunters serve as the executioners of enchanted enemy witches).

Young, less trained witches are kept vulnerable to the effects of the curses, because curses are actually part of the training process. The curses render the young witches incapable of resisting or disobeying the tutoring witch while dealing with the dark, destructive forces that could kill them instantly if they mishandled them. Once able to safely manipulate the sorcery on their own, they are finally entrusted with the hats that help to protect the mind.

- Also used in the practice of divination is the related [golden hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_hat), that serves the similar function of trapping knowledge and deflecting the mind-controlling influences of the capricious and dangerous spirits contacted to provide foreknowledge.
- The similarly shaped "Dunce hat," while not as effective, was developed to protect the mentally most vulnerable (fools and princesses) from the mind-influencing effects of  witches, especially children vulnerable to kidnapping for various nefarious functions. The relatively modest effectiveness of these dunce hats, along with the intense stigma, prevent even witch hunters from using such hats. Witch hunters simply wear a small metal skull cap (a "tin foil hat") to provide limited protection.

[image: Dunce hat]